# How to write good LINQ query for this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a LINQ Query. When i run the query it takes so much of time to perform the operation. How can i modify the query to perform good. here is the LINQ query.

**Query**

```
var model = (from items in Db.Items
                         where items.ItemNo == DD.ItemNumber
                         select new ViewModel()
                         {
                             INo = items.ItemNo,
                             BTags = (from asd in Db.BibContents where asd.BibId == items.BibId && asd.TagNo == "245" && asd.Sfld == "a" select asd.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                             Sid = (from stat in Db.ItemStatus1 where stat.Id == items.StatusId select stat.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
                             Option = DD.Option
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: create index on those tables.

Comment: Can you please give us some more information about your entity model... ideally you would use navigation properties rather than subqueries.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: And what about the model? Navigations properties?

Comment: Yes I am using navigational properties.

Comment: Well, in this query you don't use them, that's the point. I suspect that your statement fires n+1 queries. Did you check that?

Answer (score 3):

You should analyze the query in SQL Profiler and Query Analyzer. The problem is probably indexes on your tables.

Comment: +1 for this. Definitely analyse what SQL Entity Framework has generated in Profiler - sometimes it's absolutely shocking the query it has decided to run!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while your query is always working with database objects, you'd better do all your job in SQL and bring only the results to LINQ.

This will probably improve your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure EF is not causing a **Select N+1** problem.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/08/18/select-n-1-problem-how-to-decrease-your-orm-performance.aspx